# PDO Undefined Function

Tags: php, pdo

I have this class:

```
<?php
    class LLPDO extends PDO{

         public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options = array()){
            $this->link = parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
            $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        public function isConnected(){
             try {
                $this->link->query('SELECT 1+1');
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
?>
```

But when I make a call like so:

```
if(!$ibdb.isConnected()){
    $ibdb = new LLPDO(connectionString2($ini['ibdbn'], $ini['ibdbclient'], $ini['ibdbport']), $ini['ibdbusr'], $ini['ibdbpass'], array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
```

I get a **Fatal error: Call to undefined function isConnected()**. Am I calling the function wrong? Or did I do something incorrect in the class file? `$ibdb` was created ahead of time earlier in the script I'm running it in.

Comment: It should be `$ibdb -> isConnected()`.

Comment: And suddenly I feel very silly. Whoops... Thanks for the quick response! Still trying to get used to PHP.

Comment: I actually think that the php parser should throw a better error.
Maybe the parser assumes you are trying to concatenate !$ibdb with the return value of isConnected().

Comment: @IlanFrumer it may not if it thinks it's concatenating. If you have `$var = 'string'` and `function xyz() { return 'string 2' }` and do `echo $var.xyz()` you will actually and up with `stringstring2` on the screen rather than `Call to underfined method xyz() from object 'string'`. So if you don't have `function xyz()` you will end up with error for undefined function, because PHP will think you are trying to concatenate the value of `$var` wit hthe value of `xyz()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are called through the `->` operator:

```
if(!$ibdb->isConnected()){
    $ibdb = new LLPDO(connectionString2($ini['ibdbn'], $ini['ibdbclient'], $ini['ibdbport']), $ini['ibdbusr'], $ini['ibdbpass'], array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$ibdb.isConnected()){
```

`.` ? you should use arrow (`->`) to access methods/properties

```
if(!$ibdb->isConnected()){
```